# How to specify column type(I need string) using pandas.to_csv method in Python?

Tags: pandas, fieldtype

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x':['011','012','013'],'y':['022','033','041']}
Df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,type = str)
Df.to_csv("path/to/save.csv")
```

[There result I've obtained seems as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx6Ld.png)

Comment: That should be 'dtype' not 'type'.  You're outputting a CSV and then reading that into excel so it's not purely a pandas issue.  I'm not sure if this is something better to handle from pandas or excel.  Definitely you can convert to string and/or format in excel.

Comment: oops, off course "dtype".But code was correct. I need to output this zero - numbers on the step of saving to CSV. If not, I just lose them...So, I need to fix my code in Python. But how...? One solution is to add some not-number character. In this way pandas will not convert objects to numbers. But I think there is another way...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such result it will be easier to export directly to xlsx file, even without setting dtype of DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/save.xlsx')
data = {'x':['011','012','013'],'y':['022','033','041']}
Df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
Df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1")
writer.save()
```

I've tried also some other methods like prepending apostrophe or quoting all fields with ", but it gave no effect.