# Create a csv file that Excel will not mutate the data of when opening

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, string, csv

I am programmatically creating csv files using Python. Many end users open and interact with those files using excel. The problem is that Excel by default mutates many of the string values within the file. For example, Excel converts `0123` > `123`.

The values being written to the csv are correct and display correctly if I open them with some other program, such as Notepad. If I open a file with Excel, save it, then open it with Notepad, the file now contains incorrect values.

I know that there are ways for an end user to change their Excel settings to disable this behavior, but asking every single user to do so is not possible for my situation.

Is there a way to generate a csv file using Python that a default copy of Excel will NOT mutate the values of?

Edit: Although these files are often opened in Excel, they are not only opened in Excel and must be output as `.csv`, not `.xlsx`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807676/

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  However, you could provide your users a macro to use, that would import (instead of open) the csv file, and format it as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it is not possible to generate a single CSV that will display (arbitrary) data the same way in Excel and in non-Excel programs.

There are [convoluted ways to force strings to appear how you want when you open a CSV in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308324/csv-for-excel-including-both-leading-zeros-and-commas), but then non-Excel programs will almost certainly *not* display them the way you want.

Though you say you must stick to CSV due to non-Excel programs, you don't say which programs those are. If it is possible that they can open .xlsx files after all, then .xlsx would be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to declare the data type while writing the file. It seems like Excel is trying to be smart and converts the whole column to a numeric type. The output should be written directly into `.xlsx` format like so:

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/save.xlsx')
data = {'x':['011','012','013'],'y':['022','033','041']}
Df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
Df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1")
writer.save()
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136119/8819895

Comment: Hi mattemyo, I edited my post to clarify that the files must be output as csv. Is there a way to do this with that condition?

Comment: You could export a csv and a xlsx.

Comment: I agree. I am assuming some of your colleagues will be needing the raw csv files whereas others need only to display the data on excel. Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried expressly formatting the relevant column(s) to 'str' before exporting?

`df['column_ex'] = df['column_ex'].astype('str')`

`df.to_csv('df_ex.csv')`

Another workaround may be to open Excel program (not file), go to Data menu, then Import form Text. Excel's import utility will give you options to define each column's data type. I believe Apache's Liibre office defaults to keep the leading 0s but Excel doesn't.